# Can `impl From<ZST> for &'static str` (static impl) replace `impl<'a> From<ZST> for &'a str` (generic impl)?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Given the following condition:

```rust
/// Zero Sized Type
struct ZST;

/// What the ZST converts into
const TEXT: &str = "target text";
```

The following code snippets do the same thing, at least on the surface:

```rust
// static impl
impl From<ZST> for &'static str {
  fn from(_: ZST) -> &'static str {
    TEXT
  }
}
```

```rust
// generic impl
impl<'a> From<ZST> for &'a str {
  fn from(_: ZST) -> &'a str {
    TEXT
  }
}
```

My question is:

- Are they **exactly** the same? If not, what is the difference?
- Which version takes more time to compile?

Answer (score 2):

Since the reference is immutable and in return position, these are identical. That is, you can assign a `&'static str` to a variable that requires a `&'a str`, for any lifetime `'a`. Likewise, either of these can be assigned to a variable that requires a shorter lifetime because a reference with a longer lifetime is a subtype.

In fact, the only possible way to implement `impl<'a> From<ZST> for &'a str` is to return a static. That's because it has to work for any `'a`, and the only lifetime that satisfies that is `'static`.

As for a difference in compile time, it will never be significant enough to worry about.